# Can I power a 3V water pump using the 3V3 pin?

Tags: gpio, power

Zero experience here. Would it be possible to connect a simple water pump that requires 3V to the 3V3 pin of the RPI?

And in case the answer is no: Why not? What other power source would then be the easiest/cheapest to use?

Comment: It would be a good idea to specify the pump you're thinking of.  If you're going to get into hardware projects, you'll need to start thinking about current and voltage requirements, and looking at datasheets (with help).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe.

Pin 1 of the header (on all models I believe, but do check yours) provides 3.3V.  It doesn't give much current (it's rated to 50mA but more may be available in practice, according to [people who have looked at the components](https://www.element14.com/community/thread/19550/l/is-maximum-current-from-33v-pin-really-50ma?displayFullThread=true).

I have successfully run two different micro water pumps ([RS M100](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/centrifugal-pumps/0480188/), [RS M400](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/centrifugal-pumps/7026876/) off this line (via a gertboard) for several days on end (while using HDMI and USB keyboard/mouse).  *I'm probably pushing it too hard* but I haven't noticed the regulator getting warm or any misbehaviour. **NB: I'm using a Pi 2, which has a switching regulator circuit; some earlier models used a linear regulator chip which would get hot under load.  [The limit for the 3V3 supply is no longer as clear as it was, but is likely to be higher.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=633353&sid=98ea70571b1cd2fb960bfc58b8b1f127#p633353)** (official forums)

As regards back EMF -- if you have another pump in the circuit it's probably a bad idea with the M100 pump I've linked.  The M400 is brushless with its own control electronics - so won't act as a dynamo in the same way. I would assume that when we prime the pump by pulling water through, we spin the motor; this has't caused any problem with either pump.

For longer term use I intend to put a TO220 (through-hole) LD1117 voltage regulator on a piece of stripboard, run off the Pi's 5V supply (2A in my case) and run the pump off that.

If you want to switch it, use something designed for the job such as the open collector relay drivers used on the Gertboard (ULN2803A).

Comment: The gertboard does not use the 3.3v from the Raspberry Pi. It runs the 5V supply from the Raspberry Pi through a regulator to get 3.3V so it may be able to provide more power than just a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @Craig the version I have has the 3V3 regulator position unpopulated and a jumper to use the Pi's 3V3. Recently bought from Farnell.

Comment: Good to know. I guess the [User Guide](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1683444.pdf) does not match the hardware.

Comment: @Craig that's V1 of the user guide, which also lacks python examples. As I discovered just after printing it.

Comment: @Craig it might have something to do with the schange to a switching regulator on the Pi, which can drive more current.

Comment: @ChrisH The max output of a GPIO pin is 15mA. All the GPIOs on one rain can only output 50mA max. same goes for the 3.3v rail.

Comment: @PatrickCook, as we established a few days ago this isn't about the GPIOs, but about the 3V3 rail. My last paragraph handles switching.

Answer (score 5):

NO.

The pump will need considerably more than the few mA the GPIO can supply.  You also run the risk of destroying the GPIO/Pi if you spin the motor and generate back EMF.

Use the GPIO to switch a relay on a relay module designed to be used from 3V3 GPIO.

Comment: The OP is asking about the 3V3 regulated pin (e.g. pin 1), not a GPIO.

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that it *might*, with a *very* wee pump, be possible to run something off the 5V rail. You're limited to 5V and whatever amperage is left from your power supply after powering the Pi. If your only option is a 3V pump you'll need a voltage converter. Triggering a relay is a much better option.

Comment: @goobering answer based on experience on its way.

Comment: @ChrisH My mistake.  Some people use pin and GPIO interchangeably.